# Finite Groups and Isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Here is a question that I am working on:

> Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups. Show that the sets $G' = \{(g,1_H)| g \in G\}$ and $H' = \{(1_G,h)|h \in H\}$ are normal subgroups of $G$ x $H$. Show that $(G$ x $H)/G'$ $\cong H$ and $(G$ x $H)/H'$ $\cong G$.

Well there is a lot going on here, but I will try to break it down into smaller pieces.

**Rough Sketch of first part**

Suppose that we have two finite groups $G$ and $H$. Let $g$ be an element such that $g \in G$ and $h$ be an element such that $h \in H$. If we consider the direct product of these two groups, we have the following notation $G$ x $H$ and is defined by $(g,h)(g',h')$ = $(gg',hh')$, where $g \ne g'$ and $h \ne h'$.(I believe I also have to show that the elements of $G$ commute with the elements in $H$).

**Rough Sketch of Second and Third Part**

I believe I need to consider the orders of the elements of $G$, $H$ and $G$ x $H$.

That is how far I got into for the proofs. Any comments/concerns are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G' \triangleleft G\times H$ comes from $(a,b)(g,1)(a,b^{-1})=(aga^{-1},1)\in G'$ for all $(a,b) \in G \times H$.

We usually consider the "canonical" (as this is the most natural thing to do) function $$ f: G \times H \rightarrow H, \quad (g,h) \mapsto h.$$ The kernel is $G'$, so by [First Isomorphism Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems), $(G \times H) /G' \cong H$. Similar argument goes for $H'.$

Comment: What is the notation you used in your first sentence? The triangle? I am not familiar with it that's why.

Comment: Ah does it have any reference to an ideal? I did some research and that's what came up.

Comment: It means being normal, sorry :P

Comment: Ah that clears up the confusion :).

Answer (score 3):

Define

$$\phi:G\times H\to H\;,\;\;\;\phi(g,h):=h$$

It's easy to see the above is well defined and onto. Now, what its kernel? Well, now just use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Interesting. The answer I received as well also mentioned the First Isomorphism theorem, except that I have not covered that in my class just yet (perhaps in the near future).

Comment: @CartesianBread You're dealing with a question that mentions *direct products* but you haven't yet studied the isomorphism theorems? Well, that is very odd, in my opinion...

Comment: Yes DonAntonio. As a matter of fact, my textbook never mentions once about the First, Second or Third Isomorphism Theorems (after checking the index of the book). I would have to agree with you on that remark. But the topic of direct products has been discussed once in my lecture class, so perhaps it may be brought up in the near future, who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Pick an element $(g, h)$ of $G \times H$.  For every element $(g', 1_{H})$ of $G'$, examine the conjugation:
$$
(g, h)^{-1} (g', 1_{H}) (g, h),
$$
and you will see that the result also belongs to $G'$, because $1_{H}$ commutes with all elements in $H$.  This proves the normality of $G'$.

Comment: This argument can be applied similarly to prove the normality of H' correct?

Comment: Since you asked, you already know the answer.:)  Good job.

Comment: Just checking :)

Comment: I will vote up the answers for everyone who contributed to this problem later in the day (I used up all my votes that's why).